# Errors when running texmaker

Tags: errors, installing, texmaker

I just downloaded texmaker, and when I try to "Quick Build" a template, I receive either of the following error messages:

```
! LaTeX Error: File `revtex4.cls' not found.Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,or enter new name. (Default extension: cls)Enter file name:! Emergency stop.<read > \usepackage! LaTeX 
! ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

Or

```
! LaTeX Error: File `framed.sty' not found.Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,or enter new name. (Default extension: sty)Enter file name:! Emergency stop.<read > \usepackage
```

! ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!

I'm new to this and have no idea what to do.

Comment: Welcome to SE TeX. Note that you can format code by indenting by 4 spaces or highlighting and using the `{}` button in the editor. It looks as if either you do not have a complete TeX installation installed (missing packages you need) or your system is not correctly configured to find them. Chances are it is probably the former. To check, try compiling outside TeXmaker on the command line. What distribution of TeX are you using and how did you install it?

Comment: You don't have the `revtex4` document class or the `framed` package installed in your TeX distribution. See [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55437/how-do-i-update-my-tex-distribution) on updating your distribution.